# Как программно остановить поиск в WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Пишу программу, которая загружает с файла текст в WebView.
Например: есть два файла a.html и b.html, загружаю a.html ищу какой-то текст методом `findAllAsync(sometext)`. Загружаю b.html и WebView в нём продолжает искать текст.

Вопрос: как остановить поиск, что бы после загрузки других файлов он больше не искал.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение: `webView.clearMatches();`